# Headless Wordpress Next.js Blog Updates only on Redeployment?

Tags: wordpress, next.js, blogs, vercel

Is this normal for a Headless WP/Next.js setup? When a new post is published from the Wordpress admin, it does not update to the site. In order for it to show I have to go into Vercel and redeploy the site for the blog post to update. This seems a little much to have to redeploy an entire website every time you create a new post. Is this normal or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using getStaticProps/Paths to generate your blog posts, you're also going to want to implement [Incremental Static Regeneration](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration) to revalidate the data at set intervals.